# I can't tunnel traffic to another machine from a VPN without Internet access

Tags: vpn, ssh-tunneling

I have a machine with Internet access, but when I connect to the VPN, I lose internet access.

I want to tunnel an ip:port accessible from this VPN to another remote machine like this:

`ssh -R 443:180.46.221.61:443 37.197.132.19`

Where `180.46.221.61:443` is the ip:port I want to forward to the remote ip accessible from the internet `37.197.132.19`.

This is my routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 cscotun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.30.2    0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 eth0
22.0.37.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U     0      0        0 cscotun0
192.168.30.2    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
193.127.204.145 192.168.30.2    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
```

and my interfaces:

```
cscotun0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:22.0.37.7  P-t-P:22.0.37.7  Mask:255.255.255.240
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1200  Metric:1
          RX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:133 (133.0 B)  TX bytes:911 (911.0 B)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:53:9d:26  
          inet addr:192.168.30.154  Bcast:192.168.30.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe53:9d26/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:42671 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:17251 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:29262229 (27.9 MiB)  TX bytes:2038801 (1.9 MiB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2024
```

Note that I have a root account on the machine I want to tunnel traffic from, and I could change iptables rules.

Comment: Have you set net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 in the kernel parameters?

Comment: The thing is I cannot access neither internet not my lan network once connected to the VPN via Cisco anyconnect